# Suggestion on what I should use - indexer, function or other approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application built with C# and the ASP.NET MVC framework and I was wondering to make my life easier in my model I wanted to either use an indexer or a function to return the model value in a specific format to be use as display purpose in my view.

I will **simplify the example**. In my view I will display the following

```
<dt>@lblAmount</dt>
<dt>@ToAmount(Model.LoanAmount, DBLANG)</dd>
```

Instead of doing that because I will have more complex situation then simple `ToAmount` I wanted to do something like this

```
<dt>@lblAmount</dt>
<dd>@Model["LoanAmount"]</dd>
```

or

```
<dt>@lblAmount</dt>
<dd>@Model.Display("LoanAmount")</dd>
```

and in my model class:

```
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "LoanAmount":
               return ToAmount(LoanAmount, DBLANG);
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

**OR**

```
public string Display(string propertyName)
{
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "LoanAmount":
            return ToAmount(LoanAmount, DBLANG);
        }
        return null;
}
```

What is the best approach?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know how to override the ToString for a class but not too sure how to implement a ToString override for a property in a class. Thanks

```
public string FormattedValue(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Mandate, string>> p_property)
{
    try
    {
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags l_bindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase;

         // Get Class Property Name
         string l_propertyName = ((System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)p_property.Body).Member.Name;

         // Get Class Property Value
         string l_propertyValue = GetType().GetProperty(l_propertyName, l_bindingFlags).GetValue(this, null).ToString();

         switch (l_propertyName)
         {
              case "LoanAmount":
              case "SalePrice":
                    return ToAmount(l_propertyValue, DBLANG);
              case "LoanRate":
              case "PrimeRate":
                    return ToRate(l_propertyValue, DBLANG);
              case "LoanTerm":
                    return l_propertyValue;
              default:
                    throw new Exception("Property name was now found");
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //LOG ERROR
         return null;
    }
}
```

And then I can call it like so:

```
<dt>@PFI6.Resources.Models.Mandate.lblAmount</dt>
<dd>@Model.FormattedValue(m => m.LoanAmount)</dd>
```

Comment: `public string DisplayLoanAmount => ToAmount(LoanAmount, DBLANG);`. It's less trouble to write than either of the above, and it's subject to static checking by the compiler: The string `propertyName` could have a typo in it, and the compiler won't catch the error. That's an "antipattern".

Comment: Function would be better choice this is not the correct use case for using indexer which meant for a class object behave like indexed collection which is wrapped internally

Comment: I didn't put it on hold or downvote, but the comment 'which way is better' is asking for an opinion and this is a question and answer site.  I think you might consider separating the two concepts into separate questions about each where it won't be opinion based.  Hope this helps! For example, it might be better to ask 'of the two approaches, which is the best for speed optimization or memory' or something specific that you are trying to figure out.  Best approach for 'what' is the key here since it's a bit vague.  Keep in mind this helping other people out as well.

Comment: You`re right Joseph but I was trying to get suggestion on what method I should use nad if people had other ideas so maybe I should add other to the title. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

I would do none of the above, especially not with the stringed variable.

1- You could make sure that the .ToString() for each properties returns the proper results. I don't know what DBLANG is but you could set the proper culture on the thread to display in the format you want.

2- Have extra properties for display only.

```
public string LoanAmountDisplay
```

3- Create your own helper function to display the data the way you want. This is an example I did for labels (in your case, it could be a DisplayMoneyFor).

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithColonFor<TModel, TValue>(
          this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
          object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return helper.LabelFor(expression, string.Format("{0}:", helper.DisplayNameFor(expression)), htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Comment: I have a few properties in my model so if I can avoid duplicating them for format it would be a plus but I like the override as string but would there be a way maybe with reflection to get the calling property as such

`Model.LoanAmount.ToString()`

and in the override ToString function I can do a switch with the calling property and apply the format?